# Undefined reference to printf when using GCC LD cross compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-compiling, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I have an issue on gcc 9.3.1 version for ARM, my code have two file that object_1.c is empty file and for main.c as

```
unsigned char test = 100;
int main(void)
{
    /*Write code here*/
    test++;
    printf("Test lib");
    return 0;
}
```

my command when linking as the example:

```
<gcc_path>/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld.exe -L<gcc_path>/arm-none-eabi/lib -L<gcc_path>/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1 -lc -lm -T linker.ld object_1.o main.o -o run.elf
```

I have tried some ideas but it is not work. Could anyone help me with some ideas?

Comment: Please expand and post more context. Please post the whole compiler error messages verbatim as they are. Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc ? While at it, you might interest yourself in a build system that will take care of such stuff by itself, like `cmake`.

Comment: Specifically the `.../` bit is either truncated or wrong. If that has been truncated, please post the uncensored version.

Comment: .../ it is example in my program it is the directory of compiler